# Question regarding a circular loop of wire in a magnetic field on a paper

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, field-theory

I don't understand the following problem. **A circular loop of wire lies in the plane of the paper. An increasing magnetic field points out of the paper. What is the direction of the induced current in the loop?** The answer is supposedly that the induced current is in the direction of clockwise on the loop but I don't understand how it is not counterclockwise. I drew a picture that I have linked that shows my work and any help is appreciated[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzXvT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given answer is correct. **I recommend you to try again before looking for the explaination.**

Using Lenz's Law the current is induced in such a direction so that the magnetic field created due to the induced current opposes the increasing external magnetic field. 
[image]

Maybe this figure will help.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem,you need to know lenz law which states that current is induced in such a way so as to oppose it's cause.In this case,magnetic flux increases with increasing field and current is induced in clockwise direction (by lenz law as the induced field due to induced current has opposite direction,thereby reducing flux).If the field would have been decreasing,current would have been induced counter-clockwise so as to oppose the decreasing flux(as then the induced flux would be in same direction.)